# Как передать на golang функцию в функцию?

Tags: golang

Как передать на golang функцию в функцию?
есть функция1 
нужно передать в функцию2 параметры и функцию1(либо название,что б потом запустить соотв. функцию),которую выполнить после установки параметров.
как такое сделать?

Comment: А на каком этапе возникли затруднения? Сигнатура?

Comment: как написать,что функция будет принимать функцию входящим параметром?с типами понятно,а здесь не знаю как

Comment: В смысле... Неясно, как написать **тип-функцию**?

Comment: да. В остальных стринг и инт,а здесь что писать? Интерфейс или как?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Всё как обычно, просто без имён и реализации:

```
func foo(x uint8, f func(uint8) uint16) uint16 {
  return f(x)
}
```

Если сигнатура получается очень уж большой, а тип в коде используется часто, можно не двоить определения, а сделать для этого типа алиас (общая форма: `type имя тип`):

```
type transformer func(uint8) uint16

func foo(x uint8, f transformer) uint16 {
  return f(x)
}
```